# If $p$ is cts and non-negative and $ p(x) \le \int_a^x p(t) dt$ then $p=0$

Tags: real-analysis

let $p$ be continuous and non-negative on $[a,b]$ and let $c \gt 0$. If

$$ p(x) \le c \int_a^x p(t) dt$$

then prove that $p(x) = 0$ for all $x$.

Comment: you cant try to show that $p(x)>0$ and $p(x)\le 0$,this implies $p(x)=0$

Answer (score 1):

Let $P$ be the antiderivative of $p$ on $[a,b]$ cancelling at $a$ : $$P(x)=\int_a^x p(t)dt.$$
Then $P$ is differentiable, non-negative on $[a,b]$ moreover : $$P'(x)\leq cP(x)\Rightarrow P'(x)-cP(x)\leq 0.$$
Let $g:[a,b]\rightarrow \mathbb R$ be the function defined on $[a,b]$ by $$g(x)=e^{-cx}P(x).$$
Hence, $g$ is differentiable, non negative and $g'(x)\leq 0$ so for any $x\in [a,b]$, $$0\leq g(x)\leq g(a)=0$$ 
thus $P(x) = 0$ and its derivative is the zero function.